# Clean solution to deleting record in parent table when record in child table is deleted (Oracle)

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I'm currently working on this Oracle database and to keep everything simple, I have three tables: user, address, address_detail. Every address has a foreign key to a user ID and an ad_id. All address_detail records should be unique. Example below:

```
create table user (
user_id number not null,
primary key user_id
)

create table address (
address_id number not null,
user_id    number not null,
ad_id      number not null,
primary key address_id,
foreign key user_id references user (user_id) on delete cascade,
foreign key ad_id references address_detail (ad_id)
)

create table address_detail (
ad_id number not null,
primary key ad_id
)
```

The issue I'm trying to solve elegantly (or at least the best solution available) is keeping the integrity of the tables intact when a user is deleted. If a user is deleted, the address record will be deleted, leaving the address_details record as an orphan. Currently the majority of all operations are handled via stored procedures and will handle checking the integrity; however, we do have some batch jobs (from ancient times) that execute DML statements directly. One of these jobs have left an orphan record and I'm trying to prevent this from happening. The following solutions I can think of:

- triggers on delete = We used to have triggers but they have become unreliable and I have tried to stay away from using them.
- adding another column = Thought of adding a column for 'user' or 'address' to the 'address_details' table with the cascade delete constraint. While this would work, I don't like having a column just for that
- adding integrity check in procedure = The procedures that are called when an address is added could be modified to automatically check for orphans. If an orphan exists, it will log the data/event and remove it. I figured this could be part of the validation check when making sure that an address_details record doesn't already exist (since all records in AD should be unique, this will prevent an error being sent back stating that a record already exists when it shouldn't.

Of course the real tables have a lot more columns and constraints and such but this is the basis of what I'm confronted with and I was hoping I could get some ideas on the most appropriate way of handling this. One restriction is I don't believe any table modifications can be made, the tables are in stone so any changes made will have to be in the code.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Is there a possibility that different users would have the same `address_detail`?

Comment: Any of the three approaches you listed could work. I would lean towards creating the on delete trigger so that any current or future procedure or script executing DML would fire it.

Comment: The fact that you are considering the option "adding another column" indicates that `address_detail` is conceptually a child table of the `address` table.  But you have it modeled as a parent table.  What is the conceptual relationship between `address` and `address_detail`.  I.e., in the statement "n address record(s) can have m address_detail record(s)"... what are "n" and "m"?

Comment: It would help to understand why you have **three** tables to begin with. The only reasonable use case, in my opinion, is that the same user may have two or more distinct addresses, and also two or more distinct users may (in some cases) have the same address. And you only want to store info about distinct users (that's one table), only info about distinct addresses (that's another table), and the many-to-many relationship table (the table you called "address"). If that is the case, it's not clear why an address (in the details table) should be removed if **one** user at that address is removed

Comment: And if your relationship is not many-to-many (that is: if it's only a one-to-many relationship - either a user can have only one address, even if several users may share the same address; or, conversely, if a user may have more than one address, but two users can't have the same address) then you don't need three tables.

Comment: I really think triggers are the best way around in your case if constructed correctly, this is my opinion of course